# Why File, Add, Help Options are not showing on the top of my blender 2.65 for 64 bit?

Tags: blender

I am new as a Blender 3d game developer. I have installed Blender 2.65 for windows 7 , 64 bit . But some of the options are not showing. Such as Add,File,Help etc. I am unable to bring them back. Please help me.

Current View: I have marked as red color the problem section .
[image]

The View I want like this : I have marked as green color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the top left: In the first picture you see a cube, the symbol for *3D View*. In the second an icon containing the letter *i* for the *Info View* is shown. Click on it and select the *Info View* again, that's it.

Additionally you migh be interested in how to [arrange your interface](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link. And my question is closed, but where I can post this kind of question to get answer?

Comment: Some people suggest [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blender) but it contains only 40 questions tagged with blender. [Blender Artists](http://blenderartists.org) is a famous forum.